# Very slow query on GROUP BY

Tags: postgresql

I am having a really slow query (~100mins). I have omitted a lot of the inner child nodes by denoting it with a suffix `...`

```
HashAggregate  (cost=6449635645.84..6449635742.59 rows=1290 width=112) (actual time=5853093.882..5853095.159 rows=785 loops=1)
   Group Key: p.processid
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=10851145.36..6449523319.09 rows=832050 width=112) (actual time=166573.289..5853043.076 rows=3904 loops=1)
         Join Filter: (SubPlan 2)
         Rows Removed by Join Filter: 617040
         ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=5425572.68..5439530.95 rows=1290 width=799) (actual time=80092.782..80114.828 rows=788 loops=1) ...
         ->  Materialize  (cost=5425572.68..5439550.30 rows=1290 width=112) (actual time=109.689..109.934 rows=788 loops=788) ...
         SubPlan 2
           ->  Limit  (cost=3869.12..3869.13 rows=5 width=8) (actual time=9.155..9.156 rows=5 loops=620944) ...
Planning time: 1796.764 ms
Execution time: 5853316.418 ms
(2836 rows)
```

The above query plan is a query executed to the view, schema below (simplified)

```
create or replace view foo_bar_view(processid, column_1, run_count) as
SELECT
    q.processid,
    q.column_1,
    q.run_count
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        r.processid,
        avg(h.some_column) AS column_1,
        -- many more aggregate function on many more columns
        count(1) AS run_count
    FROM
        foo_bar_table r,
        foo_bar_table h
    WHERE (h.processid IN (SELECT p.processid
                             FROM process p
                                      LEFT JOIN bar i ON p.barid = i.id
                                      LEFT JOIN foo ii ON i.fooid = ii.fooid
                                      JOIN foofoobar pt ON p.typeid = pt.typeid AND pt.displayname ~~
                                                                                      ((SELECT ('%'::text || property.value) || '%'::text
                                                                                        FROM property
                                                                                        WHERE property.name = 'something'::text))
                             WHERE p.processid < r.processid
                               AND (ii.name = r.foo_name OR ii.name IS NULL AND r.foo_name IS NULL)
                             ORDER BY p.processid DESC
                             LIMIT 5))
    GROUP BY r.processid
    ) q;
```

I would just like to understand, does this mean that most of the time is spent performing the `GROUP BY processid`?

If not, what is causing the issue? I can't think of a reason why is this query so slow.

The aggregate functions used are avg, min, max, stddev.
A total of 52 of them were used, 4 on each of the 13 columns.

**Update**: Expanding on the child node of SubPlan 2. We can see that the **Bitmap Index Scan** on process_pkey part is the bottleneck.

```
->  Bitmap Heap Scan on process p_30  (cost=1825.89..3786.00 rows=715 width=24) (actual time=8.642..8.833 rows=394 loops=620944)
      Recheck Cond: ((typeid = pt_30.typeid) AND (processid < p.processid))
      Heap Blocks: exact=185476288
      ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=1825.89..1825.89 rows=715 width=0) (actual time=8.611..8.611 rows=0 loops=620944)
            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_process_typeid  (cost=0.00..40.50 rows=2144 width=0) (actual time=0.077..0.077 rows=788 loops=620944)
                  Index Cond: (typeid = pt_30.typeid)
            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on process_pkey  (cost=0.00..1761.20 rows=95037 width=0) (actual time=8.481..8.481 rows=145093 loops=620944)
                  Index Cond: (processid < p.processid)
```

What I am unable to figure out is why is it using a Bitmap Index Scan and not Index Scan. From what it seems, there should only be 788 rows that needs to be compared? Wouldn't that be faster? If not how can I optimise this query?

`processid` is of bigint type and has an index

The complete execution plan is [here](https://explain.depesz.com/s/W7qB).

Comment: I'm not at all surprised that this doubly nested query is slow.  You need to look at each part of the query and optimize it.  Also, I would be that there is a much simpler way of writing it, but without sample data not much more can be said.

Comment: Which inner query were you referring to? The inner query alias as `q`?

Comment: I don't think it will change performance, but you can [eliminate the from select](https://gist.github.com/schwern/41e95b64a4719c84bd74916b436d5f0b).

Comment: No, most of the time is spent in subplan 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You conveniently left out the names of the tables in the execution plan, but I assume that the nested loop join is between `foo_bar_table r` and `foo_bar_table h`, and the subplan is the `IN` condition.

The high execution time is caused by the subplan, which is executed for each potential join result, that is 788 * 788 = 620944 times. 620944 * 9.156 accounts for 5685363 milliseconds.

Create this index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON process (typeid, processid, installationid);
```

And run `VACUUM`:

```
VACUUM process;
```

That should give you a fast index-only scan.

Comment: Here is a gist of the whole query plan: https://gist.github.com/ilmnhxng/c15106d02b4546f3f5c9ec07982a1712

Comment: I am on a lower postgres version that does not support the `include` option. Shall I proceed to create an index like this? `CREATE INDEX ON process (installationid, typeid, processid)`?

Comment: I have adapted the answer.